# Open PDF from Base64 in React

Tags: reactjs, pdf, base64

I want to open my PDF file that is on server. I get his binary representation and content type. I currently have this function:

```
  function handleViewFile(base64Content) {
    try {
      const bufferArray = base64ToArrayBuffer(base64Content);
      const blobStore = new Blob([bufferArray], { type: "application/pdf" });
      if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobStore);
        return;
      }
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobStore);
      window.open(url, "_blank");
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error viewing file:", error);
    }
  }
```

I also tried this:

```
  const handleViewFile = (base64Content) => {
    try {
      const binaryContent = atob(base64Content);

      const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(binaryContent.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < binaryContent.length; i++) {
        uint8Array[i] = binaryContent.charCodeAt(i);
      }

      const blob = new Blob([uint8Array], { type: "application/pdf" });
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      window.open(url, "_blank");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error viewing file:", error);
    }
  };
```

When I want to view file, I get this:

[image]

I don't want the file to be downloaded.

I went to this page: https://www.ipvoid.com/base64-to-pdf/ and it returned my file. I want the exact same logic for browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
export const handleOpenPdfInNewTab = (base64Pdf) => {
  try {
    var pdfData = `data:application/pdf;base64,${base64Pdf}`;

    var w = window.open("");

    if (w) {
      w.document.write(
        `<embed width="100%" height="100%" src="${pdfData}" type="application/pdf" />`
      );
    } else {
      throw new Error("Failed to open a new tab.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error opening PDF in new tab:", error);
    // } finally {
    //   if (w) w.document.close();
    // }
  }
};
```